# Show all posts by author

Tags: php, users

I used to have a page on my site where it would show all posts by a user and it worked. This was the code it was using:

```
    <?php
    //$wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_per_page' => 12 ));
    $wp_query->query_vars["posts_per_page"] = 24;
    $wp_query->query_vars["orderby"] = 'title';
    $wp_query->query_vars["order"] = 'ASC';
    $wp_query->get_posts();
    ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
```

Nothing has changed but it recently stopped showing results. Any ideas what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should uncomment first line and add author query var.

```
 $wp_query->query_vars["author_name"] = "John";
```